# Calculating avg time of activity in the morning

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am creating a query to keep track of students' activity at school on MS Acces 2010. And I have a table as follows:

```
    ID       | Date     |  ActivityCode | Starttime | Endtime | Duration
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    1234     | 1/1/2020 |        a       | AM       | AM      | #(= 3Hours / Total number of AM per person per day) 
    1234     | 1/1/2020 |        a       | AM       | AM      | #In this case, Duration = 3/2 = 1.5 hr
    9876     | 1/1/2020 |        a       | AM       | AM      |#(= 3Hours / Total number of AM per person per day) 
    9876     | 1/1/2020 |        a       | AM       | AM      | #In this case, Duration = 3/3 = 1 hr
    9876     | 1/1/2020 |        a       | AM       | AM      |  #In this case, Duration = 3/3 = 1 hrs
    9876     | 1/1/2020 |        a       | 1200     | 1500    |  #In this case, Duration = 1500-1200 = 3 hrs
```

My current attempt on getting the duration

```sql
IIF(starttime="AM" or starttime="PM",
#(= 3Hours / Total number of AM per person per day),
CDate(TimeSerial(Val([EndTime])\100,Val([EndTime]) Mod 100,0)-
TimeSerial(Val([starttime])\100,Val([starttime]) Mod 100,0))) 
AS Duration,
```

But I am not sure how to write the #(= 3Hours / Total number of AM per person per day) part in SQL. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your expectation, what do you want to rewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```sql
Select ID, [Date], 3/Count(*) As Duration
From YourTable
Group By ID, [Date]
```

Edit - with time values:

```sql
Select 
    ID, 
    [Date], 
    IIF(
        [StartTime] = 'AM' Or [StartTime] = 'PM', 
        3/Count(*),
        (TimeSerial(Val([EndTime])\100,Val([EndTime]) Mod 100,0)-TimeSerial(Val([starttime])\100,Val([starttime]) Mod 100,0))*24
        ) As Duration
From 
    YourTable
Group By 
    ID, 
    [Date]
```

Comment: Is it possible to put it in one expression? I modify the question so that my question is more specific. I am not sure this query can still fit in. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps. See extended answer, please.

Comment: It works. Thank you. But, I don't want to use GROUP BY because I have other columns. Is it possible? or should I make another query based on this one?

Comment: You cannot _count_ without a _group by_. So, if you cannot aggregate (min, max, first, last, avg, group by) the remaining fields, create a new query with a join to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT ID, Date, (3/COUNT(*)) as Duration
FROM Table1
WHERE Starttime alike "AM"
GROUP BY ID , Date;
```

This query will get the list of IDs, and group them based on the **date**. And it will get only records with **AM** status only.

Comment: Is it possible to put it in one expression? I modify the question so that my question is more specific. I am not sure this query can still fit in. Thank you.